# How to find what caused an AUTO_REPAIR_NODES event in GKE

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

We've had a whole bunch of `AUTO_REPAIR_NODES` events suddenly occur on a previously stable GKE cluster, and can't figure out why.
We found this page: https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/node-auto-repair#repair_criteria
and the suggested items are:

- Node reports `NotReady` multiple tinmes
- Node does not return any status checks multiple times
- Node's boot disk is full for too long.

We've checked the logs, and not found any logging messages for `NotReady`.

We've checked the *pods* on the suddenly auto-repaired nodes, and they were getting traffic prior to the auto-repair event, and all of them were still returning traffic. So presumably that means that the node itself hasn't lost all connectivity.

We've checked the ephemeral disk usage on all of the nodes, and none of them have gone above 16gb (using the default boot disk size of 100gb, meaning that the ephemeral disk limit is 50gb, so we're definitely still far away)

So basically, we've got no idea what *else* to check, and also don't know *where* to check.

Any suggestions from anybody please?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Do you have master logs enabled for your cluster? The controller manager would give you more clear picture.

Another potential cause is webhooks. If they prevent any system pods from being deployed properly, the nodes will end up in a not ready state with the message "CNI plugin not initiated". Therefore, my suggestion would be to check the users defined webhooks scope and remove the kube-system namespace if included.

If you have a controller log available, please paste it here. I can then help you further.